# How to set a request proxy for requests sent by the server in nextjs middleware

Tags: javascript, next.js, server, proxy

In my project development, account services need to distinguish between formal and testing environments, which have the same domain name and different IPs. In the development environment, I need to initiate authentication requests to the test environment of the account server in the middleware. Prior to this, I had completed this task by modifying the local host file. Now, I want to complete this task through code configuration or request proxies. In my other project, I used the Whistle proxy and Axios proxy function to forward 8899 to complete this task, but in the nextjs project's middleware, Axios cannot be used, so I don't know how to implement similar functions.

I have tried to retrieve the proxy function of fetch, but I have not found any valid information

I have tried using the agent function of node fetch, but middleware uses the next fetch, which does not support the agent option